# Startscreen with static points using viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How can I make a static points in ViewPager which don't swipe with fragment? Here is an image with that layout, it's very popular this day

> [image]

What should I do? i don't have an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` as your root layout, and:

- In your layout xml also add whatever views you need and list those views after your `ViewPager` in your layout.
- Position them however you would do if the ViewPager wasn't there.
- Make their backgrounds transparent (you likely need to use custom drawables for `background=xxx`).
- If you are using TextView or ImageView make sure to set `clickable` and `focusable` properties.